# Understanding of reCaptcha statistics

Tags: statistics

I am using "Invisible Recaptcha" and in recaptcha Admin console, I can download a CSV file with stats on recaptcha usage. I have difficulties understanding what each column means:
[image: Recaptcha stats CSV file opened in Excel]

This is my understanding, but neither the tooltip header[*] nor the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#i-want-to-learn-how-recaptcha-grades-my-site-traffic-is-there-a-report-that-i-can-check) confirm my understanding. Can anyone help me ?

- no CAPTCHAs : the reCaptcha JS has been loaded but there has not been any check to figure out if the user is Human or Robot.

  - Or the Captcha test has been executed but no visual puzzle has been displaied ?
- Passed CAPTCHAs including noCAPTCHAs : nb of tests that have been executed and succeeded : some displayed a visual puzzle, some didn't ('included noCAPTCHAs')
- Failed CAPTCHAs: the user did not achieved to reply to the visual puzzle (he clicks outside the reCaptcha visual puzzle layer and it gets closed ? Or number of call to the server/verify that returned an error ?
- Total Sessions : number of session with a page with this reCaptcha (JS loaded?) ? Or number of Captcha challenge ? (you can reset and execute the Captcha multiple times on the same page). Notice that 30/01 : 25 sessions, and all other columns are zero.
- Passed sessions : what the difference with column 'Passed CAPTCHAs including noCAPTCHAs' ?
- ' Average Response Time (seconds)' : time the user spent in the captcha visual layer ? Or time Google decided between noCaptcha and visual puzzle ? Or time to load the JS library at the beginning ?

Does anyone have a better understanding ?

[*]: Text of the tooltip header

> This chart shows how many times a user or bot passed or failed an
>   individual CAPTCHA challenge on your site each day. The failed number
>   does not necessarily mean the user did not eventually solve the
>   challenge. It also shows how many times no CAPTCHA was shown after
>   someone clicked "I'm not a robot." noCAPTCHA metrics are only
>   available for sites that use the V2 API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **No CAPTCHAs** correspond to the "I'm not a robot" checkbox captcha alternative:
   [image: No Captcha]
   This is only available if you are using Recaptcha v2. (If your Captcha was setup before October 2014, chances are it has been deprecated and doesn't include the No CAPTCHA).
2. **Passed CAPTCHAs** including noCAPTCHAs reflects how many captcha tests succeeded.
3. **Failed CAPTCHAs** reflect total count of captcha tests that failed as confirmed/submitted to the server (reasons for failure include actually clicking the wrong pictures, typing the wrong code, but could also include failures as a result of corrupted data being passed or an improper API key per the list of error codes at the bottom of the [Verifying the User's Response page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).
4. **Total Sessions** reflects all your requests/connections to the Recaptcha service. If a user chooses to reload the entire page or reset the individual captcha on the page, those would also count as new captcha sessions. It also includes any [invisible recaptchas](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) where regular visitors may bypass having to fill in/participate in a recaptcha because of cookies stored on their browsers from their last visit. A session is still requested, but a captcha may not be presented to them.
5. **Passed sessions** reflect all successful Captchas and those regular visitors who have bypassed the need to reverify with captcha.
6. **Average Response Time (seconds)** reflects the roundtrip time between Google serving the recaptcha to your page and receiving a submission for verification. It is impacted by network latency as well as a user taking his/her time to respond.

Comment: I am using "Invisible recaptcha" : same of no captcha but without the recaptcha checkbox. I editted my question.

Comment: The invisible captchas still count as "No CAPTCHAs".   Google is just saying that they are not showing the user a puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html

> Since the launch of No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA, millions of internet users have been able to attest they are human with just a single click.

So no-captcha is where you get something like this:

[image]

Not sure which category would be the one I see rarely "click all the images with a car".

Comment: It looks like the passed and failed columns would include counts of the car version.